# Adding and Deleting elements on a Array of Structs Using memcpy()

Tags: c, memcpy, memmove

So I have this Contact struct and an array that holds a bunch of instances of Contact. My problem is that I use memcpy and have tried using mmove for this as well to "delete" and "add" contact elements to this array. It seems to work perfectly fine when I debug and run through the program. I can track my contacts being added and removed from the array but when I run the program without debug and without stepping through the program crashes!

This is my Contact struct:

```
typedef struct contact Contact;
typedef struct contact *pContact;
struct contact {
    char lastName[BUFSIZ];
    char firstName[BUFSIZ];
    char email[BUFSIZ];
    char pNumber[BUFSIZ];
};
```

This is how a contact is created:

```
struct Contact *contactArr[1024];
int size = 0;
Contact* CreateContact(int pos, char *info) {
    Contact *pContactNewContact = (Contact*) malloc(sizeof(Contact));
    char *lastName = strtok(info, ",");
    char *firstName = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *email = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *pNumber = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if (pContactNewContact) {
        strcpy(pContactNewContact->lastName, lastName);
        strcpy(pContactNewContact->firstName, firstName);
        strcpy(pContactNewContact->email, email);
        strcpy(pContactNewContact->pNumber, pNumber);
    }
    InsertContact(pos, pContactNewContact);
    return pContactNewContact;
}
```

These are my array manipulating functions.

```
void InsertContact(int pos, pContact *insert) {
    if (size == 0)
        contactArr[0] = insert;
    else {
        memmove((contactArr + pos + 1), (contactArr + pos),
                (size + 1) * sizeof(Contact));
        contactArr[pos] = insert;
    }
    size++;
}

void DelContact(int pos) {
    if (pos == 0) {
        memmove(contactArr, (contactArr + 1), (size - 1) * sizeof(Contact));
        contactArr[pos] = 0;
    } else if (pos <= size) {
        memmove((contactArr + pos - 1), (contactArr + pos),
                (size - pos) * sizeof(Contact));
        contactArr[pos] = 0;
    }
    size--;
}
```

Comment: Code is too incomplete. Please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But certainly `memcpy` should not be used for overlapping src and dest. Show the `memove` version instead when you update the post with the complete minimal code.

Comment: You can't use `memcpy()` if the source and destination overlap. You have to use `memmove()`

Comment: Right that is what I gathered from similar posts, although even when using memmove() there was the same problem. I appreciate the input though I will do away with the memcpy().

Comment: I think you have some off-by-one errors in your calculations. It would be easier if you wrote `&contactArr[pos]` instead of using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: And why are you assigning 0 after you've shifted the array elements? You're zapping the contact that replaced the one that was deleted.

Comment: When you're deleting a contact, you should free it before you shift the remaining elements, otherwise you have lots of memory leaks.

Comment: so in DelContact I should free(contactArr[pos]) before memmove? also I assign the contactArr[pos] = 0 so that there can be new information stored there? I could be misunderstanding something I am pretty new to C.
Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `sizeof(Contact)` multiplications should be `sizeof(pContact)`, since it's an array of pointers, not an array of contacts.

The amount you're moving should be `size - pos`, not `size + 1`.

You need to free the contact before overwriting its position in `DelContact`. You don't need to assign a null pointer to `pos`, but you can assign it to the extra element at the end.

It's not necessary to special-case `pos == 0` when deleting. All the generic calculations will work correctly using that value of `pos`.

You need to subtract 1 from `size - pos` when deleting.

`pos <= size` should be `pos < size`.

`InsertContact` should also have a check that you haven't reached the capacity of the array. I've called that `maxSize` below.

You shouldn't increment or decrement `size` if the `if` checks failed, since nothing was actually changed.

```
void InsertContact(int pos, pContact *insert) {
    if (size == 0) {
        contactArr[0] = insert;
        size = 1;
    } else if (size <= maxSize && pos <= size) {
        memmove(&contactArr[pos+1], &contactArr[pos],
                (size - pos) * sizeof(pContact));
        contactArr[pos] = insert;
        size++;
    }
}

void DelContact(int pos) {
    if (pos < size) {
        free(contactArr[pos]);
        memmove(&contactArr[pos], &contactArr[pos+1],
                (size - pos - 1) * sizeof(pContact));
        size--;
        contactArr[size] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. All of these corrections make sense to me except for when pos = size and we are inserting. Should there be a special case for that?

Comment: You don't need a special case for that. `(size-pos)` will be `0`, so `memmove()` won't do anything.

Comment: But if that is the case that pos = size then 
else if (size <= maxSize && pos < size)
will prevent the memmove() from executing. pos is an index not element position.

Comment: I had that test wrong, it should be `size <= maxSize && pos <= size`